# D3: SVG Background: Blurry

Tags: javascript, d3.js

another scripting noob playing with fire :)

I have a SVG to which I appended a rectangle.
The rectangle has a background image which appears but is blurry (oddly more so in IE than Chrome).

I've played with different image types but encounter the same problem.

Any idea how to prevent the image from being blurred ?

Code attached below - my Fiddle:-
http://jsfiddle.net/FarinU/22jcj3vc/

```
        var spaceWidth = 600;
        var spaceHeight = 300;

        var myContainer = d3.select('#abc1')
            .append('svg')
            .attr('class', 'box')
            .attr('width', spaceWidth)
            .attr('height', spaceHeight);

        var pattern = myContainer.append("defs")
            .append("pattern")
            .attr("id", "bg")
            .attr("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUser")
            .attr('width', "200px")
            .attr('height', "200px")
            .append("image")
            .attr("xlink:href", "http://www.bbc.co.uk/commissioning/images/img-bbc-one-logo-small.gif")
            .attr('width', "200px")
            .attr('height', "200px");

        var rectangle = myContainer.selectAll("rectangle")
            .data([{   }])
            .enter()
            .append('svg:rect')
            .attr("x", 10)
            .attr("y", 10)
            .attr("width", 300)
            .attr("height", 200)
            .style("fill", "url(#bg)")
            .style("stroke", "green")
            .style("stroke-width", "5");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo: it should be `"userSpaceOnUse"` instead of `"userSpaceOnUser"`:

```
.attr("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse") // <---- delete last "r"
```

See [updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mdml/sxegaxmv/).

Note that the image you are using for your pattern is only 112 by 63 pixels, and you are stretching it to 300 by 200 pixels. As a result, it will still look slightly blurry. If you shrink it back to 112 by 63 pixels, it will be crystal clear.

Comment: Thanks - appreciate the comment/answer.